# Condition value not working Properly using Jqgrid Column in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

Hello i am using Jqgrid and i want to use condition like when Column value is **ACTIVE** then Link Show otherwise Link **disable**. But condition not working Link working both condition .

Jqgrid

```
 var clscancel = '@Session["leadClose"].ToString().Trim()'  
    {

                        name: 'RecordID', label: '', search: false, width: 50, formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
                            if (clscancel == 'ACTIVE')
                                return "<a style='color:blue; text-decoration: underline; font-weight: bold;' href='../Followup/Followup?value1=" + cellvalue + "'>Followup</a>";
                            else if (clscancel == 'CLOSED')
                                return "<a id='unFollowup' style='color:blue; text-decoration: underline; font-weight: bold;' href='../Followup/Followup?value1=" + cellvalue + "'>UFollowup</a>";

                        }
                    },
```

Comment: did u inspect the value of your session variable `@Session["leadClose"]`? either it is `ACTIVE` or `CLOSED`

Comment: `But condition not working Link working both condition` => means both links are shown or either one of them are always shown?

Comment: i have only two value in @Session["leadClose"] Active and Closed .

Comment: Yes Both link are shown and one link is disable means if Active then link Active if Close then link disable you can see ID in Closed Condition . i am disable link in css .

Comment: could you please add your code that your set value to session?

Comment: Session["leadClose"]  = lmasterRecords.IsClose = mdt.Rows[0][14].ToString();

Comment: check in your controller that session contains desired value either `Active` or `Close` after you set value to your session